# Google geocoding returns response in an unexpected language

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I have a question about google geocoding API. 
For example, when I send link, where language=uk, I receive such [response](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3a287d735a64487c8f2a86cd45a9bb80). As we can see, we have 5 result objects there. The fourth object contains information about country and region in the Ukrainian language. The third object contains information about the country in Ukrainian language and information about the region in English.
Why I receive information in different languages?

Here are results objects(third and fourth)

```
      {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Lodhran",
           "short_name" : "Lodhran",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Punjab",
           "short_name" : "Punjab",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Пакистан",
           "short_name" : "PK",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Lodhran, Punjab, Пакистан",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 29.9698789,
              "lng" : 72.1114551
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 29.372238,
              "lng" : 71.35502939999999
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 29.686854,
           "lng" : 71.6673352
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 29.9698789,
              "lng" : 72.1114551
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 29.372238,
              "lng" : 71.35502939999999
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJh7mT2TF3OzkRWljvImnMH-Y",
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
  },
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "Пенджаб",
           "short_name" : "Пенджаб",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Пакистан",
           "short_name" : "PK",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "Пенджаб, Пакистан",
     "geometry" : {
        "bounds" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 34.0434647,
              "lng" : 75.38186639999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 27.7051105,
              "lng" : 69.3288726
           }
        },
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 31.1704063,
           "lng" : 72.70971609999999
        },
        "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 34.0434647,
              "lng" : 75.38186639999999
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 27.7051105,
              "lng" : 69.3288726
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJy5pBdImU3zgRoOxO0hgwnjo",
     "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
  }
```

Comment: Which language is unexpected? Can you post the results here instead of just a link?

Comment: Unexpected english language when I requested ukrainian language.

Answer (score 0):

"uk" stands for Ukrainian. The formatted address "Gojra, Lodhran, Punjab, Пакистан" is Ukrainian for "Gojra, Lodhran, Punjab, Pakistan" according to Google Translate. In the backend (where you're pulling information from), Google uses English, not Ukrainian. But since you specified language=uk, the information that would show up in the frontend is formatted in Ukrainian.

Comment: As we can see, response objects contains "address_components" which has specific information about the point. And in the fourth object we have "address_components" with object that contains "long name" = Пенджаб where "type" = administrative_area_level_1. And in the third object, we have "long name" = Punjab for the same situation. So, I don't think that the problem in google translate

Comment: The issue isn't Google Translate; I just used that to tell you what the Ukrainian characters meant. Reiterating my answer, the reason you get some Ukrainian and some English is because your query will return both backend and frontend information. Because you specified language=uk, all frontend information will be in Ukrainian. Backend information doesn't appear to the end user, so there's no need to translate it (and therefore Google won't translate it).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. Explain me, please, what do you mean under "frontend language"? And how can I get only frontend information?

Comment: Frontend is not a language. The frontend is what the user sees. If I use Google Maps and set my language to Ukrainian, then everything I see will be in Ukrainian. Hence, the language in the frontend is Ukrainian. When you query Google geocoding, they give you frontend and backend information. I don't think there's any way to only get frontend information. But once you have the results of your query, you can choose which information to use.

Comment: Ok, thank you. But when you use Ukrainian language in one place and then use english language in other place for the same word espessialy when I requested Ukrainian, I think this is a bug.

Comment: This happens when there is no Ukrainian name for Lodhran in Google Maps, the API finds the best match among available names and whatever match is found will determine the language used for the rest of the address. See the "language" parameter description in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#GeocodingRequests